# how to display the api server data values in dropdown from database(django rest framework api) in angular smart table

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

**This is my component.ts**

```
  ptype: {
            title: 'Product Type',
            type:'string',
            width:'50%',
            editor: {
              type:'list',
              config:{
                list: [{ valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
                  return row.ptype
                }
                 }]
              }
            }

          },
```

**This is my service.ts**

```
 get_type (): Observable<any[]>
      {
          return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/productype/')
                          .map(response => response.json())
                          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.statusText));
      };
```

how to display the dropdown values in ng2 smart table in api calls.

Comment: You component doesn't seem an angular compnent

Comment: We need more code, but by the rough looks of it I'm assuming you are using `http` which is deprecated and you should use `httpClient` where response doesn't have to be converted to `json` as `httpClient` does that for us automatically